# jQuery Accordion Children not hiding

Tags: jquery, accordion

So I'm trying to get my accordion menu to function so that when you have click on one menu and it opens, then click on another, the previous menu should close - but seems to automatically open then close the menu when you click on it.

Can someone check my code to see what I'm missing? I tried using the siblings function but it wouldn't function at all, and the find function is causing the aforementioned problem.

HTML

design series

```
  <div class="sideContent">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="http://www.nerosdecoshoppe.com/collections/275070-assorted-designs">Assorted Designs</a></li>
      <li><a href= "http://www.nerosdecoshoppe.com/collections/202951-kiss-me-goodnight">Kiss Me Goodnight</a></li>
      <li><a href= "http://www.nerosdecoshoppe.com/collections/202954-natures-phone-call">Into the Wild</a></li>
      <li><a href= "http://www.nerosdecoshoppe.com/collections/202949-alice-n-stripes">Alice n Stripes</a></li>
      <li><a href= "http://www.nerosdecoshoppe.com/collections/202950-magical-kingdom">Magical Kingdom</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<div>
  <a href="%20#" class="sideHeader">decoden cases</a>

  <div class="sideContent">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="http://www.nerosdecoshoppe.com/collections/202952-whip-cream">WhipCream</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.nerosdecoshoppe.com/collections/202953-rhinestone-pearls">Rhinestones/Pearls</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.sideContent').hide();
    $('.sideHeader').click(function () {
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).next().slideToggle('fast')
        //.parent().parent().find('.sideContent:visible').slideUp('fast');
        .parent().parent().siblings.find('.sideContent:visible').slideUp('fast');
    });
});
```

Here's a [jFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/76MbN/) to show it in action

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.sideContent').hide();
    $('.sideHeader').click(function () {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('.sideContent').slideUp('fast');
        $(this).next().slideToggle('fast');

    });
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/76MbN/2/)

**EDIT:** New version to cover scenario described by @nevermind

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.sideContent').hide();
    $('.sideHeader').click(function () {
        event.preventDefault();
        var $slideContent = $(this).next();
        var slideDown =  $slideContent.is(":not(:visible)");
        $('.sideContent').slideUp('fast');

        if (slideDown)
            $slideContent.slideDown('fast');
    });
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/76MbN/4/)

Comment: This works fine, but if user clicks two time on same item - submenu can't be closed...

Comment: @nevermind: fair enough. Added an answer to cover that scenario.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.sideContent').hide();
    $('.sideHeader').click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
      //  $(this).next()
    $(this).next().slideToggle('fast');
    $('#sidenav').find('a').not(this).next().slideUp('fast');   



    });
});
```

This will work. jsfiddle is extremely slow currently... http://jsfiddle.net/sinisake/76MbN/3/